# duplicate curl request when loading image causing two hits

Tags: php, curl, readfile

I've stripped this code down to the barest bones and still having a problem. Cannot make curl request cause just ONE hit to the page, it always hits twice when used with `readfile()` to load an image.

The way its supposed to work:  when user requests page, *image-url.php* it displays an image -- *download.png*.  A script within *image-url.php* makes a curl request to *http://example.com/test.php* which increments a counter and updates a database.

The problem is that the code as it appears here hits *http://example.com/test.php* twice and I cannot figure out why.

I've found that if I request the image *after* the curl request, the image does not show, the page loads instead.  The counter increments once.

If I remove the code requesting the image, the page won't load (expected behavior), the counter increments once.

There must be a way to make the image load, not the page, and increment the counter one time.

I am trying to use curl for this because the request page will vary between images and will be on various servers.  The images are always on the same domain.  Seems like the best way to go if I can make it work.

Can anybody help ?

**image-url.php**

```
    <?php
        // display the requested image ( works fine )
    $show_image = "download.jpg";
    $imginfo = getimagesize($show_image);
    header("Content-type: ".$imginfo['mime']);
    readfile($show_image);

        //  send useragent to hit counter or else won't count
    $agent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];


    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://example.com/test.php");
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $agent);
        //  makes no difference whether CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER set or not.
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    $result = curl_exec ($curl);
    curl_close($curl);
        // grasping at straws here to no affect
    unset($curl);

    //  requested image displays, hits 'http://example.com/test.php' twice
    ?>
```

**hitter.php**
This is a simple hit counter.  I removed most of the functions so it just counts hits and records ip, page name and user agent.  When included in a page it records one hit per visit, but the curl request counts twice.

```
    <?php
    include('functions.php');
    // get hitter info
    $ipAddress = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    $page_name = basename($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]);
    $browser = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];

    //database connection
    $db = new PDO("mysql:host=".DBHOST.";dbname=".DBNAME, DBUSER, DBPASS);

    $statement=$db->prepare("INSERT INTO `page_views` (`page_name`, `ip`,
    `browser`)
    VALUES ( ?, ?, ?)");

    $statement->execute(array($page_name $ipAddress, $browser));
    // this adds one record to the counter for all hits
    // except from image-url.php which increments twice
    ?>
```

**Update:**

The above code works as expected when *image-url.php* is used in an image tag: `<img src = "image-url.php">`.  It displays the image and counts one page load.  But loading the *image-url.php* directly counts two page loads.

Comment: How is `hitter.php` related to `test.php`?

Comment: Check the webserver access log, make sure `image-url.php` is only being called once.

Comment: @barmar checking I see that both *test.php* and *image-url.php* load twice with each request.  *hitter.php* (code above) is called with `include_once('hitter.php')` located at the footer of *test.php*

Comment: Maybe you have two `<img src="image-url.php">` elements on the page that's loading the image.

Comment: I point directly to *image-url.php* in the browser, which loads the image one time, just like it should but shows two page loads for itself and two for *test.php*.  When I point directly to *test.php* it shows one hit.  Baffling.

Comment: Do you see two loads in the Network tab of Developer Tools?

Comment: er, not using Developer Tools.  But the counter shows two hits in a mysql table on every update.  Can't be mistaken about that.

Comment: Sounds like something in your server configuration, maybe some kind of redirect.

Comment: If you inspect the network requests in your browser developer console, do you see multiple requests, perhaps a Range request for one?